# Delete duplicate rows that have same non-unique values in MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

How do I drop rows that have the same values in the column `title`? I do have a unique hash for all the rows, but they seem to have failed me anyway. As an added question, If my `row_id` is all over the place, can I reset it to start from 1 and re-count up to whatever number of entries that I have?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is my CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `news_archive` (
  `rowid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `rsslink` text NOT NULL,
  `timeadded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imglink` text,
  `author` text,
  `filed` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timepublished` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext,
  `polarity` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subjectivity` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`,`hash`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash_UNIQUE` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=591601 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: *I do have a unique hash for all the rows, but they seem to have failed me anyway.* Impossible. You can have the same hash for different values (collision), but you CANNOT have different hashes for the same value.

Comment: *How do I drop rows that have the same values in the column title?* Try to search by `[mysql] remove duplicates` search string.

Comment: Renumbering is evil - don't do it. Your foreign key references will  be broken. Also how do you know which "duplicate" to remove?

Comment: Is the "unique hash" on the whole row?  Or just on the column(s) that need dedupping?  Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and tell us which column(s) are part of the hash.

Comment: @Akina It's because I have a news parsing program that runs on EC2 that gets links, generates a hash from a link, checks against the database if that hash already exists, and if it doesn't, inserts it using `INSERT IGNORE`. Turns out it's not failproof because NBC decided it's a good idea to post multiple articles with the same content & same title under several different links.

Comment: @danblack They have the same 'title' value.

Comment: @RickJames I added the CREATE TABLE, the unique hash is on every row, and the duplicate rows are the ones that needs to get dedupped.

Comment: @Dragonsnap - Is `hash` a digest of just `title`?  Or of a combination of columns?

Comment: @RickJames MD5 of `rsslink`. It's done in python, though, not hashed by the database if that's even possible.

Comment: @Dragonsnap - The `UNIQUE` implies that it is already dedupped on `rsslink`.  Now you want a separate constraint on not having two rows with the same `title`?

Comment: @Dragonsnap - We need a solid definition of what constitutes a "dup".  Perhaps the combination of `source` (eg, NBC) and `title`??

Comment: @RickJames They have exactly the same `title` String, which they are allowed to have since I didn't designate `title` as a `UNIQUE INDEX`